# Foreign key constraint incorrectly formed for simple foreign key (simple)

Tags: sql, postgresql

This seems like a fairly simple issue but I haven't been able to figure out why this is occurring.

```
CREATE TABLE Instrument (
    name VARCHAR(50),
    manufacturer VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT Instrument_PK PRIMARY KEY (name),
    CONSTRAINT Instrument_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer) REFERENCES Companies(name)
);

CREATE TABLE Companies (
    name VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT Companies_PK PRIMARY KEY (name),
);
```

Returns error: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Comment: Maybe you need to first create the Companies table, then reference it in the foreign key..?

Comment: never heard of such postgres error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that both tables were referencing eachother and no matter which order, one would be referencing a table that goes not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

First time create `Companies` table, then `Instrument`. Also you have wrong comma here: `CONSTRAINT Companies_PK PRIMARY KEY (name),`.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Companies (
    name VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT Companies_PK PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE Instrument (
    name VARCHAR(50),
    manufacturer VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT Instrument_PK PRIMARY KEY (name),
    CONSTRAINT Instrument_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer) REFERENCES Companies(name)
);
```